# Override interface method in jruby

Tags: jruby

I'd like to implement the following in jruby:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

Ther ValueEventListener:

```
public interface ValueEventListener {
      void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot);
      void onCancelled(DatabaseError error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than I had initially assumed. Include the interface in a class with the on change method and pass in a proc to the listener.

```
class EventListenerValue
  include com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

  def on_data_change(data_snapshot)
    puts data_snapshot
    document = data_snapshot.val
    puts document
  end
end

event_listener =  EventListenerValue.new
ref.add_value_event_listener { |snapshot| event_listener.on_data_change(snapshot) }
```